# How not to use absolute with complex flexboxes

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, responsive

I am looking to achieve a responsive design with flexboxes, however I am facing a problem!

My problem is putting the blue and green element without using an absolute position ... assuming that the gray element is an image and not a background-color! Is it possible ?

I share with you the element that I want to achieve, each color represents an element:

[image: My element]

thank you for your feedback

Comment: put the blue, a div, and the green in a flex row. The div between them should flex-grow which should do exactly what you want.

Comment: when i set up a flex-grow, my gray and beige div moves away and suddenly i am not my blue div in the middle of my two divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use transform to achieve this.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <img src="..." alt="...">
</header>
<main>
    <div class="flexrow">
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexrow {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%); // or translate(0,-50%)
}
```

This way, the header and the main will just stack. And then you have the flexrow move exactly 50% of its own height up. And in that way, I will overlap the header and the main area.

Hopes it make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using 'position : relative'?

Below is the example and if you want to learn more, check this out!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  justify-content : center;
  aligh-items : center;
}

.box {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width:500px){
   #three {
    position : relative;
    width : 100px;
    top: -150px;
    left: -150px;
    background: blue;
  }

  #four {
    position : relative;
    width : 100px;
    top: -150px;
    left: 150px;
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box" id="one">One</div>
  <div class="box" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="box" id="three">Three</div>
  <div class="box" id="four">Four</div>
</div>
```